# xdmp:document-insert removes new lines in processing instructions

Tags: marklogic

When I try to store a document in MarkLogic (8.0-6.1) with processing instructions that contain new lines, the newlines are removed. For example:

```
let $fileURI := "/some/place/file.xml"
let $doc := 
   document {
     <?foo bar 
     another bar ?>,
     <a/>
   }
return
   xdmp:document-insert($fileURI, $doc)
```

This results in the following document getting stored:

```
<?foo bar another bar ?>
<a/>
```

When I'd rather have the document like this:

```
<?foo bar
another bar ?>
<a/>
```

Is there any way to get MarkLogic to preserve those new lines on insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic stores XML (and JSON) in their canonical form using an internal tree representation. Those newlines are probably considered insignificant, hence removed, just like XML pi, local doctype information, other insignificant whitespace. Named entities get translated to UTF-8 with `repair` enabled, or according local doctype info.

If you need to be able to export your document with original whitespace and everything, you best save it as either binary or text in MarkLogic.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do that, but xml encoding for the new line is handled with `&#xA;`

```
let $doc := 
    document {
    <?foo bar&#xA; 
    another bar ?>,
    <a/>}
```

Comment: You're right, I don't want to do that... but reasons. Unfortunately, that gets stored as `<?foo bar&#xA; another bar ?>` with no break.